# Macro inside another macro

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to put Macro inside another macro,
and I get Error message from Umbraco(exactly from the line that I put RenderMacro) :

> An error occured
> Cannot render a macro when there is no current PublishedContentRequest.
> Exception Details
> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot render a macro when there is no current PublishedContentRequest.

**The question:** what I need to do to render macro inside another macro"?

this is the Imporant parts of code of The CTAMacro that contain RenderMacro that calls "StartPracticingButton":

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
@using System.Configuration;

@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
 @{
string CTATitle = (string)Model.MacroParameters["ctaTitle"];
string CTAContent = (string)Model.MacroParameters["ctaContent"];
string CTATestId = (string)Model.MacroParameters["ctaTestId"];
string fullProductButtonText = "";
string fullProductSku = "";
   } 
 <div class="ctaFreeTest">
    <div class="cta">
        <div class="ctaTitle">
            @CTATitle
        </div>
        {
          <div class="productPageButtonContainer">
```

////////////////////////HERE COME THE RENDERMACRO THAT GIVES THE ERROR:

```
       @Umbraco.RenderMacro("StartPracticingButton", new 
    ViewDataDictionary { { "nodeid", Model.Content.Id } })
    </div>
        }

    </div>
    

</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? There are better options for things like CTA's than using macros. Macros within macros have never worked, as far as I remember. Couldn't you just use a partial view instead, for the "inner" macro?

Comment: 7.X.X

ok so you say that I need to replace the CTAmacro to partial view and inside the partial to implement the other macro?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do entirely without macros, but as a minimum I would replace the macro inside the macro ("StartPracticingButton") with a partial view instead. That should fix it, I think, without changing the way you use CTAMacro.

And as a bonus, a partial view inheriting from UmbracoViewPage should already have the Umbraco context so you don't have to pass along the node ID. You can just use Model.Content.Id directly inside the partial view.

So

```
Html.RenderPartial("StartPracticingButton")
```

should do it, given of course that you move the StartPracticingButton file from Views/MacroPartials to Views/Partials?